# Getting unexpected NaN outputs from my Fortran code

Tags: floating-point, fortran, subroutine

My Fortran code gives expected outputs for everything before `y(25)`. Suddenly from `y(25)` it starts providing `NAN` output.

There's also some weird thing happening here.
If I separate the
 `(55*f(t(r),y(r))) - (59*f(t(r-1),y(r-1))) + (37*f(t(r-2),y(r-2))) - (9*f(t(r-3),y(r-3)))` portion into a variable say `var` and do the calculation as,
`y(r+1) = y(r) + (h/24)* var`
then it starts providing weird answers.

For example after y(6) it starts providing very huge values, then goes to Infinity and starts giving `NAN` result. I checked using print statements that, in this case the `(55*f(t(r),y(r)))` part starts getting big.

Now, the weirdest case here is, if I use a

```
print*, y(24) + (h/24) * (55*f(t(4),y(23))) - (59*f(t(3),y(22))) + (37*f(t(2),y(21))) - (9*f(t(1),y(20)))
```

Just after the

```
y(r+1) = y(r) + (h/24) * (55*f(t(r),y(r))) - (59*f(t(r-1),y(r-1))) + (37*f(t(r-2),y(r-2))) - (9*f(t(r-3),y(r-3)))
```

line in `adams_bashford_four_method(t0,y,h,n)` subroutine
then I get completely expected results.

```
program d_adams_bashford_four
implicit none
integer:: n
real:: t0, t1, y(1000001), h
write(*,28)
28 format("Solution of IVP using ADAM'S BASHFORD ORDER FOUR METHOD."//)
call input_block(t0,y(1),t1,h,n)
call runge_kutta_four_method(t0,y,h)
call adams_bashford_four_method(t0,y,h,n)
call output_block(t0,y,t1,h,n)
end program

real function f(t,y)
real:: t,y
f = t**2 - t*y + y**2
end function f

subroutine input_block(t0,y0,t1,h,n)
integer:: w_inp
real:: checker
write(*,150)
150 format("Enter t0: ")
read(*,*,iostat=w_inp) t0
do while(w_inp /= 0)
    write(*,151)
    151 format("Invalid entry entered. Enter a real number: ")
    read(*,*,iostat=w_inp) t0
end do

write(*,152)
152 format("Enter y0: ")
read(*,*,iostat=w_inp) y0
do while(w_inp /= 0)
    write(*,153)
    153 format("Invalid entry entered. Enter a real number: ")
    read(*,*,iostat=w_inp) y0
end do

write(*,154)
154 format("Enter t (for the t-value you want solution): ")
read(*,*,iostat=w_inp) t1
do while(w_inp /= 0)
    write(*,155)
    155 format("Invalid entry entered. Enter a real number: ")
    read(*,*,iostat=w_inp) t1
end do

write(*,156) abs((t1-t0)/1000000), abs(t1 - t0)/5, abs(t1-t0)
156 format("Enter step size, h ([", F0.6, " <= h <=",F0.6,"] & (",F0.6,"/h) is integer)")
read(*,*,iostat=w_inp) h
if(w_inp == 0) then
    checker = (t1 - t0)/h
end if
do while(w_inp /= 0 .or. checker > 1000000 .or. checker < 5 .or. (checker - int(checker)) > 0)
    write(*,157) abs((t1-t0)/1000000), abs(t1 - t0)/5, abs(t1-t0)
    157 format("Invalid entry entered. Enter a real number [", F0.6, " <= h <=",F0.6,"] & (",F0.6,"/h) is integer): ")
    read(*,*,iostat=w_inp) h
    if(w_inp == 0) then
        checker = (t1 - t0)/h
    end if
end do
n = int(checker)
end subroutine input_block

subroutine runge_kutta_four_method(t0,y,h)
integer:: r
real:: y(1000001), t_r, k1,k2,k3,k4
do r = 1,3
    t_r = t0 + (r-1)*h
    k1 = h * f(t_r, y(r))
    k2 = h * f((t_r + (h/2)), (y(r) + (k1/2)))
    k3 = h * f((t_r + (h/2)), (y(r) + (k2/2)))
    k4 = h * f((t_r + h), (y(r) + k3))
    y(r+1) = y(r) + (1.0/6.0) * (k1 + 2*k2 + 2*k3 + k4)
end do
end subroutine runge_kutta_four_method

subroutine adams_bashford_four_method(t0,y,h,n)
integer:: r, i
real:: y(1000001), t(4), ab_calculation
do r = 4,n
    do i = 4,1,-1
        t(5-i) = t0 + (r-i)*h
    end do
    y(r+1) = y(r) + (h/24) * (55*f(t(r),y(r))) - (59*f(t(r-1),y(r-1))) + (37*f(t(r-2),y(r-2))) - (9*f(t(r-3),y(r-3)))
end do
end subroutine adams_bashford_four_method

subroutine output_block(t0,y,t1,h,n)
integer:: r
real:: y(1000001)
write(*,150)
150 format(/"The tabular form of the solution is :"/)
write(*,151) repeat("_",73)
151 format(A73)
write(*,152)
152 format(16X,"ti",17X,"|",16X,"wi",17X)
write(*,153) repeat("_",35),repeat("_",36)
153 format(A35, "|", A36)
do r = 1,n+1
    write(*,154) t0 + (r-1)*h, y(r)
    154 format(10X,F0.6,30X,F0.6)
end do
write(*,151) repeat("_",73)
write(*,155) t0, y(1), t1, y(n+1), h
155 format(//"For y(",F0.6,") = ",F0.6," the estimation,",/"y(",F0.6,") = ",F0.6,/"(using step size h = ", F0.6,").")
end subroutine output_block
```

The inputs I used is `t0 = 1`, `y0 = 0.5`, `t1 = 2`, `h = 0.02` (also used 0.01 and got exactly same error).

Comment: I strongly suggest putting your procedures into a module or at least behind `contains`.

Comment: And if you keep them like this, you **must** use `implicit none`. At least if you want any assistance from anyone who wants to keep a sane mind. Enable all compiler checks, e.g. `gfortran -g -fcheck=all -Wall`.

Comment: I already am using `implicit none` inside the main program? Should I use that inside subroutines also?

Comment: @Vladimir F, Uses of module is not allowed.

Comment: Why is use of modules not allowed? I hope you are not being taught that.

Comment: To add to what Vladimir suggests `-ffpe-trap=invalid,zero,overflow -g` - See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69735634/nan-while-adding-up-numbers-in-fortran

Comment: @Pratyya10 Yes, you must use it in every separate program unit. Only if you used your subroutines as internal after `contains`, would the program's `implicit none` suffice.